# How to click on alert box ok button using nightwatch.js

Tags: testing, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

I am working on ui automation testing using nightwatch.js, i am struggling on a point, i want to click on alert box's "OK" button but i am unable to do it because i didn't find anyway to press alert box's "OK" button on browser using nightwatch.js.

is there any way please suggest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [Selenium acceptAlert protocol](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#acceptAlert). It can be used like this:

```
browser
.url(APP_ROOT)
.waitForElementVisible('.classThatOpensAlert', 2000)
.click('.classThatOpensAlert')
.pause(1000)
.acceptAlert()
```

Comment: Yes Fredrik,

i used same way ".acceptAlert()" is the magic function which handles everything. i used in my code as following.

client.click(".myClass")
         .pause(500)
         .acceptAlert()
         .waitForElementVisible('.resultAfterPressingOk', 1000);

Comment: I was missing the .pause(1000) and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working - thanks, Fredrik!